# XtraGrid hardcode one of column's values and use Auto-filter

Tags: winforms, dataset, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid that is binded to a dataset that is populated from a stored-procedure. 
One of the columns of the dataset (InstrumentName) is not taken from the stored-procedure, but is empty.

I want to set the values on each row of this column, to something, depending on a value of another column (Id). I have a list of names and ids in memony, and I want to hardcode set the name from my list.

When I do that in the Initialized() method, I can see in the debugging that the values are set, but then they are not on the grid. Seems like the grid is repainted and my set values are lost..

I have this loop running in Initialized():

```
for (int i = 0; i < view.DataRowCount; i++)
{
    object Uic = view.GetRowCellValue(i, view.Columns["Uic"]);
    int UicInt = 0;

    if ((Uic != null) && (int.TryParse(Uic.ToString(), out UicInt)))
         view.SetRowCellValue(i, view.Columns["InstrumentName"], GetName(UicInt));
 }
```

I have also tried to do it (without looping) at DataMonitorGridViewCustomColumnDisplayText() without success..

In the end, I need to be able to use the AutoFilterRow on the new values. Up to now, everything has been possible, but not the AutoFiltering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend filling a collection from the stored procedure. You can then use that collection as the data source for the grid. Create a class with all appropriate properties including the InstrumentName which you will assign values to from your own in-memory collection.

**Update**
Based on commentary below - I believe you can use [DataRow.RowChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_events.aspx) event to trigger when a row is added. Then grab the 'Id' you want, query your in-memory collection.

I would still go back to my original recommendation. Because DataTables are loosely typed, a strongly-typed class would be much more flexible and ensure data integrity. If your DataTable has the columns Foo (datatype: int), Bar (datatype: string), and Baz (datatype: string) then create a class that mimics that structure:

```
public class FooBarBazEntity{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

You can fill a collection - `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` - quite easily with LINQ.

Comment: I don't want to use the stored procedure, because I already have this collection on the client. It's from different database and it's going to be costy to get it all the time...

Comment: *I have a grid that is binded to a dataset that is populated from a stored-procedure.* ...regardless of whether you want to use a stored procedure or not, query to a collection - that's what LINQ is for.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean... My dataset doesn't have the data I want to show on the grid. I want to populate the grid with my dataset and a calculated column actually..

Comment: I take it then that you are creating multiple data tables within a data set from the stored procedure?

Comment: No, I am creating one DataTable within a DataSet. It's just that the DataTable has an extra column (that is not in the stored procedure), that I want to populate in-code just before showing the grid..